Send message to multiple IBM MQ using Camel
I have multiple destination IBM Queue names and want to send message to all Queues successfully. In case of any exception, I want to rollback. basically either sent successfully to all Queues Or none. I am thinking to use Camel JMSCmponent. Any suggestions how to achieve this ?
In case if camel did not support, Can we use Spring JMS to achieve this?
